# Как разобраться с запросами HTTP, Sessions и вообще обменом информацией с веб приложениями на Python?

Tags: python, post, requests, get, сессия

основную проблему я описал в вопросе, очень надеюсь что ваш ответ поможет мне освоить взаимодействие с веб-приложениями. Статьи в гугле я читал, но как видите сильно это не помогло. То есть знание структуры запросов, например, есть (то что есть headers, в GET данные передаются с помощью ? key=val и тд), но как такового понимания как это работает и, самое главное, как это на практике применять, у меня не появилось.

Пишу на Python. Использую requests.

Если вдруг вы не хотите помогать мне в большом деле, то может хотя бы скажите, как автоматически проголосовать на вот этом сайте https://minecraft-server-list.com/server/399188/vote/

```
import requests


def vote_mcsl(nickname: str):
    request_url = r'https://minecraft-server-list.com/servers/voter10.php'
    data = {'ipennn': '2001%3A67c%3A2660%3A425%3Ae%3A%3A68',
            'iden': '399188',
            'ignn': nickname,
            'g-recaptcha-response': '03AGdBq24V07XQVFqJtOQ1tZodGoiWhUgLu3pnrlFw4ECVu8hugpP_M7m4afGDg2knJNPt3D03p2RpbXO55kd0v94Zj8t8fMTmvutuwVckMe8KTrMeWY-sOFZDtaFeyc6afYP5f1OUh1y8c78s6AutGoiMdiZIF5lmPaSRgdaZdnEDmbLez-9XNU1sstNP3imyTqp8wUQDSladtLmav4JqfJo1eV8UQ2gCipfYKyn3yOsurBplTSVN2pInUBOQm8Jy_AxdRNtMRStOX_NAoTm04so-yz0M0yg55deb39vuunJJ5tPXirHSXnppiAF8efwltmYSFi7lkmPSG8G9v-v_ZHahatxJn3xzuOLhWMjYgomDSuRSxFXySoKBRyJWKMdZ9vYp06-dY4xjjd3pikqjvJTCrf8aju3Y4a31XQYebHjE3EeqEoUBmmRt9e-ZbUqddSWK-58M3K7h__j6DOfKh2-YoSQikL3uDw'}
    resp = requests.post(request_url, data=data)
    print(resp.status_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vote_mcsl('dave')
```

Comment: код, который вы опубликовали в вопросе не решает задачу?

Comment: @Jack_oS, нет, он возвращает статус 404

Comment: Ну раз 404, значит вы либо обращаетесь по несуществующему url, либо скрипт обработчик на серверной стороне по переданным параметрам принимает решение не позволять вам это выполнить и сам возвращает 404. А что не так с параметрами - это надо работу того сайта изучать, тут никакие общие сведения о работе запросов не помогут

Comment: Я вас понял. А общие сведенья о Sessions вы знаете где можно узнать?

Comment: Как изучить работу того сайта, (Не связываясь непосредственно с его создателем)